# Custom retry in Reactor

Tags: kotlin, spring-webflux, project-reactor, retry-logic

I was trying to implement a retry logic in Kotlin and Reactor based on the Reactor extra package's features. What I'm trying to do is pass a list of durations, and on each `context.iteration` I'm getting the (iteration-1)th element of the list. It works **partly**, I'm always getting an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` on the last iteration, which is more than I wanted, although I've provided a max number of retries - the size of the list. The retries are running though, in the given duration and "correct" number of times (surely because `IndexOutOfBoundsException` prevents more), only this exception (and it's root cause) bothers me.

This is my custom BackOff interface:

```
interface MyCustomBackoff : Backoff {
    companion object {
        fun getBackoffDelay(backoffList: List<Duration>): (IterationContext<*>) -> BackoffDelay {
            return { context -> BackoffDelay(backoffList[(context.iteration() - 1).toInt()]) }
        }
    }
}
```

And my Kotlin extension is:

```
fun <T> Mono<T>.retryCustomBackoffs(backoffList: List<Duration>, doOnRetry: ((RetryContext<T>) -> Unit)? = null): Mono<T> {
    val retry = Retry.any<T>().retryMax(backoffList.size.toLong()).backoff(MyCustomBackoff.getBackoffDelay(backoffList))

    return if (doOnRetry == null) {
        this.retryWhen(retry)
    }
    else {
        this.retryWhen(retry.doOnRetry(doOnRetry))
    }
}
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at `reactor.retry.AbstractRetry#calculateBackoff`, you could find that there is special `BackoffDelay` named `RETRY_EXHAUSTED`. And it returns when `retryContext.iteration() > maxIterations` (not `>=`) after `backoff.apply(retryContext)`

```
if (retryContext.iteration() > maxIterations || Instant.now(clock).plus(jitteredBackoff).isAfter(timeoutInstant))
    return RETRY_EXHAUSTED;
```

So, if you have 2 custom backoff delays in the list, there will be 3 backoff delays generated by `calculateBackoff`.

You could change your `MyCustomBackoff` like so (excuse me for Java, I'm not familiar with Kotlin):

```
public interface MyCustomBackoff extends Backoff {
    static Backoff getBackoffDelay(List<Duration> backoffList) {
        return context -> context.iteration() <= backoffList.size() ?
                new BackoffDelay(backoffList.get(Long.valueOf(context.iteration() - 1).intValue())) :
                new BackoffDelay(Duration.ZERO);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I missed that one!

Comment: Actualy, it looks like issue. I think `calculateBackoff` should check exhausted condition then call `backoff.apply(retryContext)`. I'll ask about it on Github.

Comment: It seems illogical to me as well. Thanks for pursuing it!